# PowerPoint VBA to Hide Ribbon

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to use VBA to hide the ribbon in the "Normal" view and make it inaccessible, similar to how the ribbon is not displayed or accessible in the "Reading" view.

I have used the following method in Excel, but I am unaware of any similar method for PowerPoint:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",false)
```

I am aware that the "Visible" property of other command bars can be set as follows:

```
CommandBars("Status Bar").Visible = False
```

However, the "Visible" property cannot be set for the the "Ribbon" in the same fashion.  Specifically, the following code will not hide the Ribbon or make it inaccessible in PowerPoint:

```
CommandBars("Ribbon").Visible = False
```

Is there any alternate method for PowerPoint to achieve the same effect as the Excel VBA code above?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

The above minimizes the Ribbon. To hide it completely:

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have revised the question to remove ambiguity regarding the term "hide".  I am looking for a solution that both "hides" the Ribbon *and* makes the Ribbon inaccessible in the default "Normal" view, similar to the Excel VBA posted in the question and replicating the Ribbon's absence in the native "Reading" view in PowerPoint.

Comment: @z32a7ul Is there a similar command to maximize the ribbon after you "MinimizeRibbon"? I tried "ShowRibbon" and other variations, but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: @Kevin There is no different comment for that but if you issue the command `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"` again, then it will toggle this flag back, and the ribbon will be maximized. The same is true for the other one, executing it again will make the ribbon visible.